# How would you write a regex to remove all html attributes except type="A", type="1" and type="I"?

Tags: html, regex

How would you remove all html attributes with regex except the type="A", type="1", and type="I" attributes?

The following html:

```
<ol type="A" lang="en-CA" style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
  <li><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
<ol type="I" style="font-weight: bold;">
  <li><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
```

Should become:

```
<ol type="A">
  <li><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
<ol type="I">
  <li><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: A dedicated parser will *always* be better than any regex you can come up with. Because a regex will choke on [perfectly valid HTML markup like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/), whereas a DOM parser won't.

Comment: You [would not. At all.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: (type="[\w]").*> - maybe this could work. Btw this is a good site for testing: https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: Is this [http://regex101.com/r/vL9vL6/3](http://regex101.com/r/vL9vL6/3) close to what you're looking for ?

Comment: yes @hex494D40, looks like it - thank you. I will look into using a htmlparser also based on comments from Amal and Golez, thanks

Comment: Shall I paste it down as an (possible) answer if you found it useful :) ?

Comment: sure, since it actually does answer the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer doing it using regular expression try the following one

```
(<[a-z]+\stype="[A|I|1]")(?:[^>]+)?
```

Replacement:

```
$1
```

Input:

```
<ol type="A" lang="en-CA" style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
  <li type="A" s="something"><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
<ol type="I" style="font-weight: bold;">
  <li><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
<ol type="1" style="font-weight: bold;">
  <li type="I" another="attribute"><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
```

Output:

```
<ol type="A">
  <li type="A"><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
<ol type="I">
  <li><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
<ol type="1">
  <li type="I"><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
```

Simple usage using JavaScript

```
var s = '<ol type="A" lang="en-CA" style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">';
var p = /(<[a-z]+\stype="[A|I|1]")(?:[^>]+)?/g
console.log(s.replace(p, '$1'));
```

Output:

```
<ol type="A">
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vL9vL6/4)